# Ubuntu for netbooks

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I just bought a new toy [an Asus EEE 1015PN](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0046A8WGO). I have no experience with ubuntu but I wish to learn to use it. I wish to hear your advice.

optional & off-topic: I didn't dig the subject, but is android a valid choice for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's a netbook, I suggest you to try the [Ubuntu Netbook edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/get-ubuntu/download). The page I'm linking to has a detailed guide with screenshots on installing it. All you need is a spare USB stick with at least 2GB space.

I suggest you to *Try ubuntu* before actually installing it. In that way, you can see if it really fits your need.

Answer (score 1):

Since the askubuntu site is for objective questions and answers, you should get more advices at a forum like this http://ubuntuforums.org/

At [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) you can read what kind of questions are expected here:

> You should only ask practical,
>   answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty,
>   open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other
>   questions off the front page. To
>   prevent your question from being
>   flagged and possibly removed, avoid
>   asking subjective questions where …

Answer (score 1):

Go for it Dole! I own a very similar netbook (Asus EeePC 1005PE), and Ubuntu Netbook Edition (10.04 LTS) was my first experience with Linux. It was love at first sight with its amazing netbook-oriented interface.  You will see how great it optimizes space, and how superior it is when comparing to Windows when it comes to small 10" screens.

I have mine dual-booting with factory-installed Windows 7 Starter... but... to be honest, in 10 months using it i may have booted Windows like 5 times only.

And remember that with Ubuntu, you dont have a limited, "starter" edition. You a full fledged OS, complete with all software including an (Open-)Office Suite.

I would suggest 10.04 Lucid Lynx over 10.10 Maverick Merrkat on 2 reasons:

1. 10.04 is an LTS (Long-Term Support) version. Meaning support and updates for it will last longer (3 years) than the regular version 10.10 (1.5 years). Also, it (usually) have more stable packages, less experimental software. Its built to last longer and be more trouble-free.
2. 10.10 lanched a whole new revamped interface. Some loved it, some hated it. But all agree that its very different from what most people are used to. So, coming from Windows world, i guess you might feel more "confortable"  with the more "traditional" 10.04 laucher.

Both have amazing hardware suppport for Asus EeePCs. You will find that most (if not all) FN+Keys will be working out-ot-the-box. So as Wireless, LAN, Sound, 3d-Video, Webcam, Microphone, etc. And the greatest: no need to install ANY driver! No more "go to device website and download or install setup CDs" anymore!

For netbooks, specially Asus EeePC ones, its a great choice, one I recommended whole-heartedly.

That said, here it is:

http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook